# How to use command in bash script to read multiple lines in a file and pick one number to define a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have been trying to write a code using bash script to read a file1.dat and find a particular number and specify that to a variable.

For example, in file1.dat,

```
10  10   1   0
0.8499360E+02  0.6965500E-09  0.6965500E-09  0.2022791E-08  0.5000000E-15
1.000000000000000E-004
CAR
HgRO
5.26290852    -15.00879477  301     -1.68859640      1.00000000
-15.009  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
-14.941  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
-14.874  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
-14.806  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
--////////-----/////---
```

From the above file I want read only the number `-1.68859640` and declare a varible "EFERMI" in the script.

So, code should look like,

```
EFERMI=$(head -n +6 ../DOSCAR | tail -1)
```

But problem with this command whole line comes.

So, can you please help me to get the right command for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `awk`:

```
EFERMI=$(awk 'NR==6{print $4}' file1.dat)
```

`NR` is the record number (line number) and `$4` is the 4th element of that line.

Comment: Nice, but you're missing the input file.

Answer (score 1):

After you've got the line with the needed number you can use `read` to extract the needed number from it. If it has a fixed position as a *word* within that line than you can simply skip needed number of words like this:

```
infile="../DOSCAR"
LINE="$(head -n +6 "$infile" | tail -1)"
read _ _ _ _ _ _ EFERMI _ <<<"$LINE"
```

You can (and probably should) also read other parts of the file and check the format and contents to make sure that you've got the right input and the right number.

Answer (score 0):

One solution has already been provided by Zrin. Here are others:

Using `cut`, you can select any field, given that you know the field number:

```
EFERMI=$(head ....|tail ....|cut -d ' ' -f 7)
```

If you don't know the field number, but know that it is the last field, you can do a

```
EFERMI=$(LINE##* }
```

where *LINE* is as in Zrin's solution. This assumes that LINE doesn't have trailing spaces. Of course you can always remove trailing spaces before extracting the field.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you for your answers. It really worked. I have used the "cut " it is short to use in my script. Many thanks to every one.